# Oracle REF data type

Tags: sql, oracle, inheritance, plsql, user-defined-types

I'm trying to make this query work. I want to insert in Oficina_bancaria's nested table Cuentas the ref() of a Corriente_udt row stored in Cuenta table:

```
(SELECT ref(TREAT(VALUE(c) AS Corriente_udt)) FROM Cuenta c WHERE c.IBAN = '1654ES6639071895270420369756');
```

Corriente_udt is a subtype of Cuenta_udt which is the data type of Cuenta table.

This is the error I'm getting:

```
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

I've already tried this:

```
(SELECT ref(c) FROM Cuenta c WHERE c.IBAN = '1654ES6639071895270420369756');
```

But I also get an error:

```
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected REF USER.CORRIENTE_UDT got REF USER.CUENTA_UDT
```

And this is my full query:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (SELECT o.Cuentas FROM Oficina_bancaria o WHERE o.Codigo = 1439 AND o.Direccion = 'Alameda de Esperanza Vives 978 Valencia, 32678') (SELECT ref(TREAT(VALUE(c) AS Corriente_udt)) FROM Cuenta c WHERE c.IBAN = '1654ES6639071895270420369756');
```

Comment: This seems to be a fragment of a larger query, and we don't know anything about your data or data types - e.g. where the inheritance fits in. Please edit your question to include [a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please give the `CREATE TYPE` statements for `USER.CUENTA_UDT` and `USER.CORRIENTE_UDT` and the `CREATE TABLE` statement for the `Cuenta` table.

Comment: @AlexPoole question edited!

Comment: You're still missing statements for `Cliente_udt` and `Oficina_bancaria_udt` types and for the `Oficina_bancaria` table.

Comment: And what is it you are trying to achieve as the syntax of your full query does not look correct.

Comment: @MT0 question edited.

Comment: Some DML statements with sample data populating the table and an example of your expected result would help to check that the answers given are what you are requesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to insert in Oficina_bancaria's nested table Cuentas the ref() of a Corriente_udt row stored in Cuenta table

Its not entirely clear what you want from your description, but I think you want to to add a reference to the `Cuentas` column (a `corrientes_array` data type) in an existing row of the `Oficina_bancaria` table.

**Query**:

```
UPDATE Oficina_bancaria
SET   Cuentas = COALESCE( Cuentas, Corrientes_array() )
                MULTISET UNION
                Corrientes_array(
                  ( SELECT TREAT( REF(c) AS REF Corriente_udt )
                    FROM   Cuenta c
                    WHERE  c.IBAN = '1654ES6639071895270420369756' )
                )
WHERE  Codigo    = 6356
AND    Direccion = 'Cuesta Hector Montes 15 Puerta 5  Cuenca, 02539'
```

or, maybe:

```
MERGE INTO Oficina_bancaria o
USING (
  SELECT TREAT( REF(c) AS REF Corriente_udt ) AS Corriente_ref
  FROM   Cuenta c
  WHERE  c.IBAN = '1654ES6639071895270420369756'
) c
ON (
    o.Codigo    = 6356
AND o.Direccion = 'Cuesta Hector Montes 15 Puerta 5  Cuenca, 02539'
AND c.Corriente_ref IS NOT NULL
)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET o.Cuentas = COALESCE( o.Cuentas, Corrientes_array() )
                  MULTISET UNION Corrientes_array( c.Corriente_ref );
```

(which should not insert a reference into the array if it is not found in the `Cuenta` table).

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3144d81a3ba9baea4767c49257377f73)*